# How can I show a custom toast notification above a scrim with jetpack compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a custom snackbar defined by a SnackbarHost:

```
@Composable
fun SnackbarHostCustom(snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        val (snackbarhostref) = createRefs()
        SnackbarHost(
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(snackbarhostref) {
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                    top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = gridMultiple(2))
                },
            hostState = snackbarHostState,
            snackbar = {
                Snackbar(
                    backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                    action = {},
                    elevation = 1000.dp
                ) {

                        Text(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .constrainAs(informationText) {
                                    top.linkTo(parent.top, margin = gridMultiple(2))
                                    bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, margin = gridMultiple(2))
                                    end.linkTo(parent.end, margin = gridMultiple(2))
                                    start.linkTo(informationImage.end, margin = gridMultiple(2))
                                    width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
                                },
                            fontSize = 14.sp,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                            color = Color.Black,
                            text = snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.message ?: ""
                        )
                    }
                }
            },
        )
    }
```

In my layout I am opening a `ModalBottomSheetLayout`, and at this exact moment I want to show my custom toast. Because the ModalBottomSheetLayout opens, I want to dim the background to create a larger contrast for the modal. I do this using a scrim like so:

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(
    sheetState = state,
    scrimColor = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.6f),
```

This all works fine except for the fact that my custom SnackbarHost displays *below* the scrim. So it is dulled by the black background, so it is difficult to see. I want this snackbarhost to *always* show above anything no matter what. I tried using z-index, but it did not work. I tried applying it to the constraint layout modifier, but no dice. I also tried opening the snackbar from the context of the modal, since that is where I want to see it anyway, but it just added it to the content of the modal (the part that is dragged up and down), not the top of the parent view.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?